# How to debug WordPress React plugin?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, debugging, plugins

I change one on the tsx file in a plugin. The developed plugin is in `wp-content/plugins` folder. I installed locally WordPress with Mamp.

The thing I do not understand, I changed the tsx, but when debugging page in browser, breakpoint stops running in that file, but that file does not have the changes I made. How is it possible?

I am debugging in Chrome. I see there is a `localhost:8888` entry but where running is catched is a different item, it is `tiket-on-wordpress` - this is the name of my plugin item.

So how is that file does not have my changes?

[image]